# Datalist.Visible always false?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I've done this a million times without a problem, and I'm stumped at this one.

I have a DataGrid:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="gridDeptEmployees" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                 ItemStyle-CssClass="hovertable" ViewStateMode="Enabled"> 
                    <ItemStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelect" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="firstname" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="lastname" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="employeeNumber" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:DataGrid>
```

This datagrid is bound to a list of objects:

```
Dim userList as New List(Of User)
userList = getList()
gridDeptEmployees.DataSource = ulst
            gridDeptEmployees.DataBind()
```

I can see users in the list when I set a breakpoint and step through it, **but the grid is never visible. The visible property is always false!**

I've tried explicitly setting the visible property, but it doesn't honor my changes. I even tried adding my DataKeyNames, but that didn't work.

What am I missing here? Should I switch to a different control?

Comment: maybe is inside some other control that is non-visible, like a PlaceHolder, or a Panel, or a custom control

Comment: Aristos - want to make this an answer so I can give you the credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you can not see a control (not rendered on page), and debug it and see that the visible is false, then is probably because is inside some other hidden control, like a PlaceHolder, or a Panel, or a UserControl.

Check to see if a parent control is hidden to find your reason.